# powershell filewatch why called multiple times for one file change?

Tags: .net, powershell

I tested the script below I just modified a file content once but I get console write multiple times, why ?

```
function test {

### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $filewatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    #Mention the folder to monitor
    $filewatcher.Path = "C:\D_EMS Drive\Personal\LBLOG\"
    $filewatcher.Filter = "*.*"
    #include subdirectories $true/$false
    $filewatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $filewatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $writeaction = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    Write-Host "changed"            
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
#The Register-ObjectEvent cmdlet subscribes to events that are generated by .NET objects on the local computer or on a remote computer.
#When the subscribed event is raised, it is added to the event queue in your session. To get events in the event queue, use the Get-Event cmdlet.
    Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Created" -Action $writeaction
    Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Changed" -Action $writeaction
    Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Deleted" -Action $writeaction
    Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Renamed" -Action $writeaction
    
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, from [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher) (emphasis added): "_Common file system operations might raise more than one event_. For example, when a file is moved from one directory to another, several OnChanged and some OnCreated and OnDeleted events might be raised. Moving a file is a complex operation that consists of multiple simple operations, therefore raising multiple events. Likewise, some applications (for example, antivirus software) might cause additional file system events that are detected by FileSystemWatcher."

Comment: here as I said I just modified one file.

Comment: Yes, but note the possibility of AV software being the cause. You can also try to reduce the number of [notification filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter), to see if that makes a difference.